# For each student make comma-separated list of all courses for which he enlisted

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Could somebody help me for each student make comma-separated list of all courses for which he enlisted?

I need to modify a Contoso University application with a comma-separated list.

Student Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string studentEnrollment, string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
        ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

        var students = studentService.GetAll();

        var studentViewModel = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Student>, IEnumerable<StudentViewModel>>(students);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            students = students.Where(s => s.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                   || s.FirstMidName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
        }
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "name_desc":
                students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastName);
                break;
            case "Date":
                students = students.OrderBy(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
                break;
            case "date_desc":
                students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
                break;
            default:
                students = students.OrderBy(s => s.LastName);
                break;
        }

        int pageSize = 3;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

       return View(students.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

Course Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
        {
            int pageNumber = page ?? 1;

            var courses = courseService.GetAll();

            var coursesViewList = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Course>, IEnumerable<CourseViewModel>>(courses);

            var model = coursesViewList.ToPagedList(pageNumber, PageSize);

            return View(model);
        }
```

Student Model:

```
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Enrollment Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:g}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }

    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
```

Course Model:

```
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CourseID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Credits { get; set; }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
```

View:

```
    @model PagedList.IPagedList<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Students";
}

<h2>Students</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Student", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <p>
        Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)

        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </p>
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Last Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            First Name
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Enrollment Date", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DateSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            Date Of Birth
        </th>
        <th>
            Courses
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstMidName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EnrollmentDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateOfBirth)
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
<br />
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
    new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

Please tell me somebody the easiest way to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the model for the `Enrollment` class, assuming it has a `Course` property which returns a Course object, you can just do this in your view (where `item` is the `Student` object in your `foreach` loop):

```
@string.Join(",", item.Enrollments.Select(e => e.Course.Title))
```

Comment: The name 'model' does not exist in the current context

Comment: My typo, used `model` instead of `item`.